# SQLite db file not found on Android

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I am not able to find the db file where the database adapter is created a db and table. But i could see that the data is getting saved but i am not able to find my db file in my directories.
But i am able to save the entries and viewed on my screen.
Here is my DBAdapter class where i am creating the db..

```
public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "clientList.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_CLIENT = "CLIENT";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
    private static final String  COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME = "CLIENT_NAME";


    private static final String query = "create table test_1 " + " (COLUMN_CLIENT_ID integer primary key, COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME text)";


    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase;
    private static DBAdapater dbAdapaterInstance;


    private DBAdapater(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sqliteDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(this.context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION).getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static DBAdapater getDbAdapaterInstance(Context context){
        if(dbAdapaterInstance == null){
            dbAdapaterInstance = new DBAdapater(context);
        }
        return dbAdapaterInstance;
    }


    public boolean insert(int clientId , String name ){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_ID,clientId);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME,name);
        return sqliteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CLIENT,null,contentValues)>0;
    }

    public boolean delete(int ClientID){
        return sqliteDatabase.delete(TABLE_CLIENT, COLUMN_CLIENT_ID + "=" + ClientID,null)>0;
    }

    public boolean modify(int ClientID , String newClient){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME,newClient);
    return sqliteDatabase.update(TABLE_CLIENT,contentValues,COLUMN_CLIENT_ID + "=" + ClientID,null)>0;

    }

    public List<DataBean> getClient(){
        List<DataBean> clientInfo = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(TABLE_CLIENT , new String[]{COLUMN_CLIENT_ID,COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME},null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                DataBean clientBean = new DataBean(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getString(1));
                clientInfo.add(clientBean);
            }
        }
        return clientInfo;
    }

    //purpose of this class is to help outer class
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        public DatabaseHelper(Context context , String databaseName , SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory , int dbVersion){
            super(context, databaseName , factory , dbVersion);
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(query);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

}
```

Here is my bean class

```
public class DataBean {

    private long id;
    private String clientName;
    private String address;


    public DataBean(){
        super();
    }

    public DataBean(long id , String clientName){
        this.id = id;
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify any path, it will be stored in `databases` folder of your application directory.

Comment: it is  not stored anywhere. I could notice now that if i remove the string containing the CREATE TABLE, its still even working. Kindy let me know how to fix this

Comment: As you mentioned you were able to save and retrieve data, it's not about `CREATE TABLE`. You must find it in `databases` folder.

Comment: I agree with you, but i am not even able to find that databases folder. I even checked once after your first comment. I even checked for the filename in the main directory. It is not present over there. If you could give your email address please , i can just eloborate what issue im finding

Comment: What do you mean by `main directory`? Try to run `adb pull /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/clientList.db` command in terminal. You will get the DB into your local environment.

Comment: adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
adb: error: connect failed: no devices/emulators found
.....I got this error after trying that command

Comment: adb: error: remote object '/data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/clientList.db' does not exist
Still the error persists.

Comment: oh ya, i missed to rename the path, still the error persists.Could you please check your mail box as i have dropped a mail to you.Kindly post your comments there, as there is limitations in posting comments here